# How to make the camera look in direction of object X axis

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I'm trying to apply a first-person camera to a cannon.js raycast vehicle using three.js as the renderer. I can apply the position and quaternion of the vehicle to the camera, however the camera looks along the vehicle's z axis (up). I'd like to look forward along the x axis.

I tried:

```
camera.quaternion.copy(carBody.quaternion);
camera.rotation.x += Math.PI * 0.5;
camera.rotation.y += Math.PI * 0.5;
```

but that doesn't quite work. After applying the vehicle's quaternion I think I want to rotate the camera 90 degrees around the car's y axis and make the camera's "up" axis along the car's z axis but not sure how to do that.

I'd also like to be able to move the camera to a fixed position on the vehicle, eg. the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, this is actually pretty simple. Just attach the camera as a child of the vehicle mesh. Eg:

```
vehicleMesh.add(camera);
camera.position.set(-0.25, 0, 1);
camera.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
camera.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;
```